# Magnolia CMS and Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, magnolia

We are started implementing a new project using spring MVC.
I am trying to understand How Magnolia CMS will work with Spring MVC.
I gone through lot of documents but still I am not 100% clear on the following information

- How to integrate Magnolia into Spring?

  is it like Spring application will run on one machine and magnolia will run on other machine. And some plugin(I guess Blossom) will connect both the systems?
- Where exactly blossom will come into picture?
- How we can handle static pages ?

Any inputs...will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

> Where exactly blossom will come into picture?

It is a magnolia module, if you have a maven project just add the maven dependencies to the project (from the magnolia archetypes you may find one with blossom already included - have a look [here](http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/~gjoseph/dont-build-magnolia-build-your-projects)).

While for that concerns how the http requests are processed look at his presentation [here](http://www.slideshare.net/Magnolia_CMS/getting-healthy-with-magnolia-blossom-and-spring).

You should be able to find also some some helpful videos on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9I5f-S20wg) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFBMB5bU8nU).

> How we can handle static pages ?
>   I would have a look to the standard templating kit or [here](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/My+first+template).

Hope it helps.